# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (shortcode-box)

Tags: jquery, shortcode, wp-admin, javascript

I have a Wordpress theme that the author is no longer maintaining, and has stopped functioning properly with the update to Wordpress 3.x. Over the past few months, I have been working to resolve the issues with the theme.  Most of these issues have been related to JavaScript, and I have been able to fix most of them.  I'm finally down to one I can't fix:

This theme contains a function in the admin panel to add new shortcodes that a user can create and performs all the steps correctly except the last: send the shortcode to wordpress editor.

Chrome inspect gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function --- shortcode-box.js:1305
>
> shortcode.sendToEditor --- shortcode-box.js:1305
>
> (anonymous function) --- shortcode-box.js:16

The lines referred to by the errors:

line 1305

```
sendToEditor :function(){
        window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand('content', 'mceInsertContent', false, shortcode.generate());
    }
```

line 16

```
jQuery('#shortcode_send').click(function(){
            shortcode.sendToEditor();
        });
```

I attached the shortcode-box.js file: http://www.samuguerra.com/shortcode-box.js

Can anyone help me? Excuse my English, as I wrote this with the help of Google Translate

Comment: Help, please! :'(

Comment: If you're using TinyMCE 4.x, you'll need to use `tinymce` instead of `tinyMCE`. Actually, can you try `window.tinymce.editorManager.get("content").execCommand("mceInsertContent", false, shortcode.generate());`?

Comment: Thanks Schism! 

I tried your solution but still not working :(

Now the Chrome Inspect gives me the following error: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined  --- shortcode-box.js:1305

Comment: I have some free time tonight; I can look into this deeper for you, but it'll have to wait about 12 hours.

Comment: What shortcode are you trying to send to the editor?  As a hunch, whatever shortcode you are trying to pass is not a member of the case statement is the `shortcode_box.js`

Comment: The shortcode-box.js file working properly until I updated Wordpress to version 3.5, so I guess the fault is with the jQuery function that will be obsolete. I've tried a Wordpress 3.4 and works well the shortcode. Failure is when the wordpress version is 3.5 or higher.

Thanks to both